# Framework7 datepicker modify events after initializing

Tags: html-framework-7

Hello Framework7 team,

How do we modify (renew) the events after initializing for example on a month change (onMonthYearChangeStart) ?

```
var today = new Date();
var weekLater = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 7);

var calendarEvents = myApp.calendar({
input: '#calendar-events',
dateFormat: 'M dd yyyy',
events: {
  from: today,
  to: weekLater
}
});
```

Kind regards,
Mario

Comment: Actually i am also facing the same problem,So when framework7 calendar initialize it creates DOM for 3 months,Previous,current and next and then adds events.You can directly change the object of calendar.but it will reflect when html change,when you go next by 2 months it changes html for current.If you find solution please post here also,Thank You

Comment: did you find any answer to this? I also need a way to add events on pagination. I am using the `onMonthYearChangeEnd` to tap into the month change, but I need to now load more events. I use an array of event dates. This must be somehow possible via the API?

Comment: I have a similiar question posted which may be of help, I have a solution but still looking for better solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126743/framework7-calendar-events-load-with-ajax-onmonthadd

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looping through the events and added/removed classes to the date object like below:
So with every month change I called the following script.
I also used a minus and a plus class to get red and green dots.

```
eventsPlusDataValues = dataSet.map(function(a) {
    if(a.hasValue && a.value > 0)$("[data-date="+a.startDate+"]").addClass('picker-calendar-day-has-events').removeClass('picker-calendar-day-has-eventsMinus').addClass('picker-calendar-day-has-eventsPlus');
    if(a.hasValue && a.value < 0)$("[data-date="+a.startDate+"]").addClass('picker-calendar-day-has-events').removeClass('picker-calendar-day-has-eventsPlus').addClass('picker-calendar-day-has-eventsMinus');
    return a.startDate;
});
```

It is a while back so I hope I did not forget something.